# jsGrid - get data typed by the user in a search navGrid

Tags: d3.js, jqgrid

I'm trying to bind a table and a graph using d3 and jqGrid library. For that I have to get the search typed by the user in the searchbox (my table looks like this : http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/)

I've found this function : 
    grid.getGridParam("postData").filters
but I don't know how to use it. I thought about the trigger event "jqGridToolbarAfterSearch" to get the data after each search but doesn't seems to work...
If someone has an idea I'll be very grateful!
Thanks.

Ps : if the same method exist to set data, I'm interested too.

Comment: Could you provide some demo where you use d3 and to describe what kind of information you want to display in the jqGrid and, which kind of filter you need to apply to the data.

Comment: I started from this chart : http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281
The selection of an item return an array with the min and max values that I selected.

I want to link this data to the filter of my table (in both side but for the moment I'm looking for a solution to get filters of the table and then, apply them to the chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I correctly understand your problem. I suppose that you first converts the CSV data of [the demo](http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281) to some more continent data format: array of items with some properties (`name`, `economy`, `cylinders`, `displacement`, `power`, `weight`, `mph`, `year`). Then you can use `datatype: "local"` and `data` as the input data. I suppose that the user apply the *local* filter and then you want to get the filtered data

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid (it's the fork which I develop) then you can get `lastSelectedData` parameter (`var filteredData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "lastSelectedData");`) to have the array of filtered items (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm)). After that you can use d3 with the filtered items.